# Add an NSView around cursor?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

Simple question, starting out with macOS stuff – I’d like to create a small radial menu around my cursor, top-most, above whatever application is currently active, whenever a specific mouse button is pressed.

I have the specific mouse button over all application down, but I’m wondering where I need to draw that `NSView`, i.e. “topmost”. I guess on iOS this would be at the `UIWindow` level, but would `NSWindow` be the wrong approach here?

Comment: I’ll admit to the cardinal sin of not having delved too far yet ;)

Comment: and how would the users be able to select/click on any of the options _around_ the pointer if the options are always relatively floating _with_ the pointer? I don't see that idea was actually thought through well...

Comment: Click third mouse button, radial wheel appears. User can scroll over wheel, left-click on an option. Wheel pops where cursor WAS when it was opened, does not track cursor :)

Comment: then creating an `NSWindow` based on the mouse pointer's current location sounds reasonable.

Comment: Worked a treat. If you want the kudos, feel free to leave an answer :)

Comment: okay, I just did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is purely an opinion-based question, but basically if you want to present any custom content on the desktop, that should use `NSWindow`, and you can customise the window's content for your wish.

---

***NOTE:*** you can find more information about the `NSWindow` class in [Apple's **Class Reference Docs**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow).